# role based spring boot accessing failure

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

```
 @Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                .requestMatchers("/users/**").hasRole("USER")
                .requestMatchers("/public/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated());

        return http.build();
    }

@PostMapping("/login")
    public String loginPOST(@RequestParam(value = "email") String email, @RequestParam(value = "password") String password) {
        LOGGER.info(email + " " + password);
        UserDetails user = customServiceDetails.loadUserByUsername(email);
        if (user != null) {
            LOGGER.info(user.getUsername() + " " + user.getPassword());
            Authentication authentication = customServiceDetails.authenticateUser(email, password);

            if (authentication != null && authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
                LOGGER.info(user.getUsername() + " has " + authentication.getAuthorities());
                return "redirect:/users/dashboard";
            }
            return "redirect:/login?error";
        }
        return "redirect:/login";
    }

2024-03-10T15:57:18.663+03:00  INFO 19248 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] g.d.controller.AuthenticationController  : bbc@gmail.com has [ROLE_USER]
2024-03-10T16:08:17.508+03:00  INFO 19248 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] g.d.controller.AuthenticationController  : bbc@gmail.com baris35
Hibernate: select u1_0.id,u1_0.email,u1_0.password,u1_0.user_lastname,u1_0.username from users u1_0 where u1_0.email=?
Hibernate: select r1_0.user_id,r1_1.roleid,r1_1.role_name from user_role r1_0 join roles r1_1 on r1_1.roleid=r1_0.role_id where r1_0.user_id=?
2024-03-10T16:08:17.511+03:00  INFO 19248 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] g.d.controller.AuthenticationController  : bbc@gmail.com $2a$10$elY28DLwjvtcJyViVcS4du5cCoJ2QPFioWQo0acjpwVsd.o4sDVkW
Hibernate: select u1_0.id,u1_0.email,u1_0.password,u1_0.user_lastname,u1_0.username from users u1_0 where u1_0.email=?
Hibernate: select u1_0.id,u1_0.email,u1_0.password,u1_0.user_lastname,u1_0.username from users u1_0 where u1_0.email=?
2024-03-10T16:08:17.566+03:00  INFO 19248 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] g.d.controller.AuthenticationController  : bbc@gmail.com has [ROLE_USER]
```

I created basic java security application and I added properly a  few user into database however I can use register page but if I access who has roled a user does not allow browser "403"

I check each user has a role in database

I put here 2 different code snippets, those are not working together under same class hierarcy.